# Wordpress dynamic content in index file

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress.

I am using customizr theme in latest version of wordpress.

```
I just put my html in theme index file.
Now i am not getting the posts dynamic content,when click on posts link.

I know i am missing some syntax that makes the content area dynamic

How would i make my home page content area dynamic.

Please help ..

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

  <li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```